# Android - Design time access to Custom Attributes

Tags: android

In **Android** - Is there a way to access custom attributes at design time. I have a custom view that has a custom attribute. I would like to be able to access any custom attributes that have been defined for the view at design time.

All the defined attributes works fine in run time, I would like to know how can i do it in design time.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is worded in a confusing way. Are you trying to change the stuff put into the views at runtime? If so, in the standard Activity, after your setContentView(...), you can do things like

```
Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.reallyAwesomeSauceButton); 
button.setText("Click me!");
```

Just check out the Android documentation to see what you can do with a view at runtime. There's quite a bit

Comment: No, I want to be able to set the property and see the update in the design time"graphical layout" like when we set android:text="Click Me" for the Button and go see the graphical layout you will see the update you did (the button text is "Click Me".

Comment: If I'm reading you correctly: do you want to use set...Drawable or use an XML selector?

Comment: I want to be able to see it in design time for any of my custom properties like: mycustom:text, mycustom:xxxx ... etc

Answer (score 0):

this might be a bit late...

you can read all attributes in your views constructor using the AttributeSet.

```
public class myView extends LinearLayout{

    private String mCaption;

    public myView(Context context,AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context,attrs);

        mCaption = attrs.getAttributeValue("http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.myView","myAttribute");
        TextView tv = new TextView(context);
        this.addView(tv);
        tv.setText(mCaption);
    }
}
```

this only reads the raw values though, no references are resolved etc.